# How to Stream Audio from PC through Bluetooth

Tags: android, audio, streaming, bluetooth

Here's what I am trying to do. Capture any audio being currently played on the PC and stream it through Bluetooth and then play it through the Android device paired with the PC. I have worked with Bluetooth a little but very basic stuffs. And I have very less idea on how to go about on this. My target device is Android 2.2 (and above). I guess I have to use Bluetooth profiles, but not too sure. Also, I am not aware of any other caveats that I may have to face.

Would anyone like to point me at the correct direction. Any tips, links would help. Thank You.

Comment: I am pretty interested in finding out whether you had any progress on that matter. I was also thinking about something like that but on Android to Android so that my pal can listen to the same thing I am without the necessity of sending him the whole audio file.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I moved on to other projects. May be I will start something similar later but I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the capability / profile that your android device supports, for streaming you normally will use the A2DP profile and the android device will need to support the A2DP sink role. Typically this role is supported by Stereo headsets , speakers etc. Android phones do not support sink - phones are A2DP source (or initiator of the streaming)

Comment: Is there any way a phone can be used as a sink using some kind of library or such?

Comment: Also the stack on the PC needs to support audio and allow BT devices to enumerate as Audio devices, if they support audio profiles like A2DP.